# Как средствами PHP или JS изменить текст в HTML файле?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Я выгружаю готовую HTML страницу, отображается как бланк с данными.Есть поля которые нужно заполнить цифрами, либо изменить в них данные.Каким образом можно автоматизировать?
схема html->скрипт->измененный html.Направте, если сталкивались подскажите, что и куда.Хотелось бы решить данную задачу.Если есть решение, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Если нужно генерить html - то php, если изменять на клиенте - js. Направил?

Comment: Да)Буду гуглить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insertAdjacentHTML()` разбирает указанный текст как `HTML` или `XML` и вставляет полученные узлы (`nodes`) в `DOM` дерево в указанную позицию. Данная функция не переписывает имеющиеся элементы, что предовращает дополнительную сериализацию и поэтому работает быстрее, чем манипуляции с innerHTML.

Запись:

```
element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text);
```

`position` указывает положение `element`, и может принимать одно из следующих значений:

`beforebegin`
Перед element .

`afterbegin`
Внутри element, перед первым дочерним элементом (потомком).

`beforeend`
Внутри element, после последнего дочернего элемента.

`afterend`
После element.

Пример:

```
// <div id="one">one</div> 
let d1 = document.getElementById('one'); 
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="two">two</div>');

// Результат
// <div id="one">one</div><div id="two">two</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

С помощью PHP нельзя поменять уже выведенные данные. Когда пользователь видит перед собой страницу и начинает совершать какие-то действия с ней, PHP уже завершил работу.

Ваш выбор - javascript.
если используете jquery, то данные можно менять, например, так:

```
$('#id_div').text('Ваш текст');
```

На чистом js:

```
document.getElementById("id_div").innerHTML="Ваш текст";
```